# Creating Vue application: vue create does not work

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli

I am trying to create a vue app with vue-cli on a ubuntu running on a vagrant & virtual box on Windows 10 and i get the following error which I cannot solve.

```
npm ERR! path /vagrant/vuetest/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin- 
utils/package.json.4118558811
npm ERR! code ETXTBSY
npm ERR! errno -26
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! ETXTBSY: text file is busy, rename 
'/vagrant/vuetest/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin- 
utils/package.json.4118558811' -> 
'/vagrant/vuetest/node_modules/@babel/helper-plugin-utils/package.json'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/vagrant/.npm/_logs/2018-06-07T01_37_02_093Z-debug.log
ERROR  command failed: npm install --loglevel error
```

Any ideas? anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think othiym23 got your answer on npm issues :

https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/9979

othiym23 : "My guess is that you're both running Linux inside Vagrant on a Windows host, because ETXTBSY is almost always due to Windows not wanting to let the guest OS remove or move a file. Generally, this happens when you have a cmd.exe process open in a directory, or are looking at the folder with Explorer, or have a file in there open in a text editor."

Comment: The problems appear to be related to the bin-links issues that are discussed in the link you provide Lucille. The way i got around it however was to use yarn to install Vue and it worked.

Comment: interesting, I did not test yarn yet